# SSRS - not clickable link in a text field

Tags: reporting-services, hyperlink, new-window

I need to open a SSRS report in a new window using the action property Go to URL of a text field.

I try this.

[image: Text box property]

The code in the Select URL field is:

```
="javascript:void(window.open('http://myreportserver/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/foldername/reportname&rs:Command=Render&parameter01=" + Parameters!Parameter01.Value+ "&Parameter02=" + Parameters!Parameter02.Value + "','_blank'))"
```

The problem is that in the SSRS report, the field in which I have set the property Action Go to URL appears like a simple text field without a clickable link on it.

If I insert in the Action Go to URL a link like

```
="www.stackoverflow.com"
```

or like

```
="javascript:void(window.open('http://myreportserver/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/foldername/reportname&rs:Command=Render&parameter01=parameter01','_blank'))"
```

the text field become a clickable link.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

I have created an hidden field and I have wrote in this one the expression

```
="javascript:void(window.open('http://reporting.italia.texa.org/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/Amministrazione/test2&rs:Command=Render&Parameter01=" + Fields!Field01.Value + "&Parmeter02=" + Fields!Field02.Value + "&Parmeter03=" + Fields!Field03.Value + "&FornitorePrimaNota=" + Fields!Codice.Value + "&Anno=" + CStr(YEAR(Fields!DataMovimento.Value)) + "&Quarter=" + Parameters!Quarter.Value + "','_blank'))"
```

In the text property of the clickable field I have wrote this in the Select URL in the Action section

```
=ReportItems!URL.Value
```

[image: Text Property]

[image: URL expression]